# Was the SNES really a "highly pirated" console?

Tags: snes, copy-protection

I just watched the YouTube video [How Nintendo Stopped Bootleg Games on the Nintendo 64](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5uOK0nR934).

The presenter claims that the SNES had a massive pirate scene and you could "easily buy" one of several "backup" devices to play games for free, and "games were uploaded to FTP servers". Uh. Sure. My own experience, growing up in those days, is:

1. I never saw a single person with a pirated SNES game or any kind of "backup" device.
2. The only ad for such a device that I ever saw, for a "Super Wild Card DX 32", was in an old game magazine which, when I telephoned them, just said that it was illegal to sell them and obviously wouldn't send one to me. (Supposedly they did for some time, years prior.)
3. Even just playing NTSC (imported) games on a PAL SNES constantly had to be "defeated" with new devices/mods.
4. Even if I had such a device, I didn't have an Internet connection anyway to "fetch from FTP sites", nor would it have been fun to slowly load in ROMs from floppy disks.

The author of the video seems to be from the UK. Maybe things were different in that specific region, and that's why he claims that there was such a "rampant" piracy of the SNES? This really struck me as odd. I've always associated the SNES with near-100% legitimate sales and that it was only the PlayStation and then especially the Dreamcast and first Xbox that were the "pirate consoles".

Comment: I don’t know that an authoritative answer is possible as the claims you’ve heard have plenty of wiggle room, and would be hard to verify even if precisely quantified. That said, to contribute as someone alive in the UK during the era: I saw a copying device once, at a show, and it cost more than the Super Nintendo itself. I never saw one in anyone’s house or in a regular shop. And this is as we segued away from home computers, so people had and were familiar with floppy disks, playground piracy was otherwise common, etc.

Comment: Have you tried to ask the person making the video and the claim from where the information comes?

Comment: @UncleBod It is impossible for me to communicate with the author of the video, so no.

Comment: To add another anecdotal UK observation: I've never (knowingly) encountered a pirated or fake SNES cartridge to this day, whereas I have come across some Game Boy (and Advance) ones. But I may have led a sheltered childhood, as I didn't hear of conosle-based piracy until the days of PS1 modchips.

Comment: Minor additional comment: having checked out the video, his accent is Australian. I did a quick web search and it seems his professional history is all in America, which would tally with the reference to renting games from Blockbuster Video, which had only very small footprints in both Australia and the UK (at least, under its own name) during the Super Nintendo's peak years.

Comment: Here's a link to a UK magazine article in August 1992 describing the Super Magicom backup system priced at £250. https://archive.org/details/N-Force_No_2_1992-08_Europress_Impact_GB/page/n6/mode/1up?view=theater The SNES had only launched in the UK four months earlier, with a recommended price of £150!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_backup_device